# Can MongoDB eval with nolock option safely write to the database?

Tags: mongodb, locking, eval

It states in the FAQ section http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/#faq-concurrency-operations-locks that:

> "(...eval takes...) Write lock. If used with the nolock lock option, the eval option does not take a write lock and cannot write data to the database."

Under eval documentation we can read that:

> "(...eval option...) nolock does not impact whether operations within the JavaScript code itself takes a write lock."

I've also checked and it's possible to write to database from eval with nolock option.

Does this mean that:

1. using eval that writes to the database ie. via `db.coll.update` etc. with nolock option won't issue an error but it's prohibited, ie. the behaviour is undefined or may lock the database? If this is the case, why it's not mentioned in eval documentation in red?
2. using eval which writes to the database with nolock option is possible and issuing a commands inside eval like `db.coll.insert` or `db.coll.update` will use their own write locks but the whole eval will hold read lock. In that case, isn't the nolock option unnecessary and should always default to false?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the whole statement from the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/) in context:

> - By default, **eval** takes a global write lock before evaluating the JavaScript function. As a result, **eval** blocks all other read and write operations to the database while the eval operation runs. Set **nolock** to **true** on the **eval** command to prevent the **eval** command from taking the global write lock before evaluating the JavaScript. **nolock** does not impact whether operations within the JavaScript code itself takes a write lock.

So the default case here has a purpose in that what is generally being attempted when this is being invoked to to perform some kind of "bulk" change to data, and as a concept you generally don't other things changing that while this is going on. So there is the reason for obtaining a lock by default.

In the **nolock** case, you need to consider that it is possible that some uses of **eval** may actually have nothing to do with reading or writing data. I really do not see the reasons myself, but I have come across a few cases where people want to do it. In that case it would not make sense to obtain a lock that would otherwise be blocking for no particular reason.

In the case where you set **nolock** but go ahead and update data anyway, then you have to consider what is actually happening underneath. Sure, you are executing JavaScript and there should only be obtaining a lock ( and probably only at the collection level ) for the write that is explicit to the current operation. Seems reasonable.

But you are also doing that within the same JavaScript execution thread as what you are reading with, as well as likely running through something like a "for" loop. While each operation should technically yield at some point, the reality is that within that execution thread there is not much control over this and the end result will be something near equivalent to the global lock that could have been obtained in the first place.

All of that said, use of **eval** should be a "last resort" measure and really even then only for solving "one off" problems with data maintenance and migration. Setting up continued use in production is probably not a very good idea at all and will be likely to cause problems.

Consider the alternatives always, as is more or less covered here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/server-side-javascript/